# Horizontal ScrollView in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout, horizontalscrollview

I am making an advertising application in Eclipse and wish to display scroller ad's in horizontal ScrollView. Also I need to rotate this scroller view after every 5 seconds.

The following is the configuration

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/hsHorizontalAds"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/llHorizontalAds"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Please suggest.

Comment: Please show us some of the solutions you've attempted and explain why they are unsatisfactory.

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/hsHorizontalAds"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/llHorizontalAds"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this way,[this](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/ui/horizontalscrollview/android-horizontalscrollview-example/) is what you looking for

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

        android:layout_width="fill_parent"

        android:layout_height="fill_parent"

        android:orientation="vertical" >



        <HorizontalScrollView

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"

            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:layout_marginTop="50dp" >



            <LinearLayout

                android:layout_width="wrap_content"

                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:orientation="horizontal" >



                <Button

                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"

                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                    android:text="Button1" />



                <Button

                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"

                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                    android:text="Button2" />



                <Button

                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"

                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                    android:text="Button3" />



                <Button

                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"

                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                    android:text="Button4" />



                <Button

                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"

                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                    android:text="Button5" />



            </LinearLayout>

        </HorizontalScrollView>



    </LinearLayout>
```